# what happen with references on gui objects when the root is destroyed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What happens to slave widgets when the parent widget is destroyed?

How can we faster remove all references on objects related with GUI after calling my_gui.destroy() in python tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

The references stay around according to the normal python rules. The underlying widget objects are all destroyed when the root window is destroyed.